# How can I get an inter-process lock on a SeekableByteChannel?

Tags: java

If I use `FileChannel` I can get advisory locks with its `lock()` method.

However if I use the newer - and presumably preferred - `Files.newByteChannel(Path,OpenOptions...)` instead I get a `SeekableByteChannel` from which I cannot see a `lock()` method to try and obtain an advisory lock on the backing file.

I could just suck it up and use `FileChannel` but my question is whether there is an obvious way from `SeekableByteChannel` that i’m Just missing somehow.

Comment: You can't. The `lock()` method provides inter-process locks, not intra-process locks. You need to use synchronization or a semaphore for intra-process locks.

Comment: Damn phone and its auto-correct. `inter-process` is what I am after

Comment: So use `FileChannel`. There is no reason to assme the other is 'preferred', unless you need the extra facilities it provides, and certainly no reason to cripple yourself in the process.